# Set an Element inside a div to 100% height

Tags: css

i want to have an element inside a div set to height 100%. The element (an ul Element) must be   set relative. The list items are set absolute but in reference to the parent element.

See the example: http://jsfiddle.net/mbecker/ee78G/2/

How to set the green ul Element to 100% height?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think you can give a `ul` a height because it is not a block element. Is it the `ul` you want to be 100% tall, or the `li`s inside of it?

Comment: @JesseWebb `ul` is a block-level element iirc.

Comment: @antisanity - I thought only the `li` elements were block-level. I tried to find out for sure but the W3C site (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ul.asp) doesn't say either way. How would you find out for sure?

Comment: @JesseWebb http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/ul.html#ul-display

Comment: If an element isn't a block element, you can always set `display: block` to make it one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I removed the `height: auto !important` on `#main`. Then, I was able to set `height: 100%` to `#list`.

I'm not sure if the `height: auto` is necessary though.

http://jsfiddle.net/KBHcs/

To give more explanation, the `height: auto !important` makes the content define the height of the element and the !important was overwriting the `height: 100%`. In this case, the "sd" was the only thing in the `ul` as the `li` are absolutely positioned, and therefore, are not part of the document flow.

Comment: Ahh! With the explanation you deserve a plus one! ;) Always remember future visitors to your answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can set the #list element to use absolute positioning and then set the top and bottom coordinates.  Here's an example of your modified jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ee78G/11/

Comment: +1 - I didn't know this was possible, will this work in any browser?

Comment: Yes it works in any of the modern browsers.  IE8+ I believe, Firefox,  Chrome & Safari.